# How to transfer some letters to uppercase dynamically in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

i got a problem when i was making to capitalize dynamically. In my code i can capitalize any letters but it is not dynamic,the program should guess which letter should it capitalize.For example some text comes from JSON and there should be some comparing that checks texts letters and users inputed letters and then he should guess which letter he must capitalize. if there is some solution for this, please tell me. here is my code :

index.html

```
<textarea  id="fieldId" class="textarea" style="resize: none" cols="30" row="2" ui-mask="{{typetext}}" ng-model="model"  data-ng-trim="fasle" ng-trim="false" ng-focus="expression"> 
</textarea>
```

scipt.js, thats what i was trying to do.

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
    controller.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        var transformedInput = '';
        if (inputValue) {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
                if (i === 0 || i === 5) {
                    transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                } else {
                    transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        }
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
            controller.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            controller.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
    });
})
```

and controller

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
    $scope.typetext = "Some Text";
    $document.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}])
```

Comment: Post the full directive please. When should it be uppercase and when should be lowercase ?

Comment: its very extensive code.Should i post it anyway ? when you type it should automatically transform lowercase letter to uppercase.But it should be compared to the text that comes from json

Comment: You almost gave the full directive. The link part is the biggest one generally. What is `ui-mask` ? So lowercase letter should be changed to uppercase and that's it ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CgfgLgkmr85WHum1ReP4?p=preview . Look i made that, but thats only for the text what i defined and it works only for that text.

Comment: Did you checked my code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform text to uppercase dynamically from JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480425/transform-text-to-uppercase-dynamically-from-json)

Comment: no1 answered me and i tried to post same question again :(